# Server side events scaling in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployment in Kubernetes for a rest API that has 3 pods, each pod has 2 containers. The deployment type is ClusterIP. I am not extremely familiar with Kubernetes but I have the task to scale a server-side events connection to this server.

Basically, whenever a client is connecting using the EventSource JavaScript object to the backend the connection is opened on 1 pod. I have a route on the backend that whenever a request comes in, a server-side event is triggered, but the catch is that the request can come on one pod and the client can be connected on another pod. I need to notify all clients regardless of the pod they are connected to. Is there a way to achieve this behavior in Kubernetes? I do have to mention that the front end is built using a very old JS framework and it's hard to integrate modern javascript frontend libraries at this time.

So far I have tried the google cloud pub/sub server, cloudamqp with Rabbitmq, but the same behavior happens. If I publish a message to a queue that all pods are connected to, only one of them gets the message.

Answer (score 0):

> If I publish a message to a queue that all pods are connected to, only one of them gets the message.

yes, post messages to a single *queue* will not solve your problem.

You could instead post them to a *queue* for each client, e.g. multiple queues.

Alternatively, you should not use *queues* but a topic where messages are preserved so that it can have multiple readers.